# Деструктор в контейнерах?

Tags: c++

Допустим, есть класс:

```
class MyClass1
{
    int a;
    string s;
    ...
};

class MyClass2
{
    list<MyClass1> lst;
}
```

Как правильно для `MyClass2` - объявить деструктор, который бы полностью уничтожал контейнер?
Лично я пишу так:

```
~MyClass2()
{
    this->lst.clear();
    this->lst.shrink_to_fit();
}
```

Но `this->lst.clear();` вызывает деструктор для каждого объекта контейнера, а - 
`this->list.shrink_to_fit();` - "сжимает" размер буфера в соответствии с `size`. Но, например, когда `size=0, capacity=1`, т.е в любом случае, контейнер будет находиться в памяти, пусть даже и "условно" - не имея в себе элементов.

**Вопрос**: как полностью удалить контейнер из памяти?

Comment: Контейнер сам вызовет все нужные деструкторы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уже не первый раз замечаю подобные ситуации, когда в деструкторе какого-либо класса, содержащего контейнеры (типа `std::vector`, `std::list` и т.п.), управляющие временем жизни своих объектов зачем-то выполняют ручную очистку. В большинстве случаев это делать не нужно, когда умирает объект, содержащий контейнер, автоматически убивается и контейнер. В свою очередь деструктор контейнера вызывает деструкторы содержащихся на тот момент элементов контейнера и так по цепочке.

Таким образом, если элементы контейнера имеют (или не требуют вовсе) деструкторы, полностью уничтожающие себя, никакой ручной работы не требуется. Но если, скажем, по какой-то причине, вы храните в контейнере что-то типа сырых указателей, для которых ранее была выделена память, то, конечно, такие указатели нужно освободить (выполнить соответствующую форму `delete`) до того, как информация о них (адреса, по которым выделена память) будет уничтожена деструктором контейнера. В частности пройтись по ним соответствующим циклом. Но даже в таких случаях лучше положиться на подходящие умные указатели (например, `std::unique_ptr` или `std::shared_ptr`), чтобы избежать ненужной ручной работы по уничтожению (написанию деструктора).

Answer (score 4):

После `shrink_to_fit` пустого контейнера `capacity` будет равно 0. А в деструкторе класса `MyClass2` ничего писать не надо, так как деструктор списка сам все подчистит.

Comment: VTT, спасибо за ответ. Не могли бы Вы объяснить, более подробно, как именно работает деструктор списка? Его внутреннее строение.

Comment: @BadCatss поштучно вызывает деструкторы элементов списка, как минимум. Остальные детали не существенны для пользователя класса.

Answer (score 1):

Если контейнер list хранит именно элементы MyClass1, а не указатели на них, то в деструкторе с этим контейнером ничего делать не надо, он сам всё почистит при разрушении объекта типа MyClass2.

Answer (score 0):

Компилятор генерирует некоторое количество "умолчательного" кода для поддержки ООП. В том числе *умолчательный деструктор*, если вы не объявляете свой кастомный вариант. *Умолчательный деструктор* вызывает деструкторы всех экземплярных полей класса, т.е. в вашем случае и `list`.

А `std::list`, в свою очередь, достаточно умён, чтобы прибрать за собой, поэтому вашей задачей будет лишь реализация логики деструктора `MyClass1`, экземпляры которого хранятся в списке, если в этом есть необходимость (`MyClass1` содержит неуправляемые ресурсы, требующие ручного освобождения).